# Wordpress Custom Endpoint rest api (Post Method) not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

This is my Custom End point but its says 
"No route was found matching the URL and request method" 
i added in the theme folder function.php file.
when i changed the method 'POST' to 'GET' it works fine for get method
.htaccess file is ok any other plugin like securty or other rest api plugin not installed
only "WP REST API plugin" is activated

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'myfunction' );
function myfunction() {
register_rest_route( 'app', '/addmeta', array(
    'methods'  => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'vendor_serve_route'
) );
}

function vendor_serve_route(WP_REST_Request $request_data ) {
// Fetching values from API
$data = $request_data->get_params();`enter code here`
$user_data = array( 'user_login'     => $data['first_name'],
                    'user_email'     => $data['user_email'],
                    'nickname'       => $data['user_name'],
                    'first_name'     => $data['first_name'],
                    'last_name'      => $data['last_name'],

                    );


 return ['Data' => $user_data];


 }
```

Comment: The code seems fine to create an endpoint (although I would advise you to create a plugin just for this), so it should be an error in your request for the endpoint. Are you also changing your request to HTTP's `POST` method? You have to change it in the endpoint and wherever you're making the request.

Comment: Thanks.You are right .The problem is HTTP

Comment: @SmartBird I tried your example .... but it failed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already stated in the comments but now with a little bit more explanation:

The code seems fine to create an endpoint, so it should be an error in your request for the endpoint. The problem is that you're just changing the endpoint's HTTP method but not the HTTP method of the actual request to the endpoint.

This code will create an endpoint that accepts `POST` requests to `YOUR_DOMAIN/wp-json/app/addmeta`.

It's not a good practice to add a lot of code to the `functions.php` file, as it will get really big and hard to maintain.

You should create a plugin (it's a really simple process) for this and put the new code there. This way, it's isolated and you can even reuse it in other apps easily.

To create a plugin you need to:

- Create a new directory under `/plugins` for your plugin
- Create a `.php` file in that directory with the same name as the directory
- Include a header comment in that main file that describes your plugin

Example:

- Directory: `.../plugins/my-api-endpoints`
- File: `my-api-endpoints.php`

And then include the comment in the file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My API Endpoints
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: This plugins handles the submissions for my API.
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: John Doe
 * Author URI: http://johndoe
 */

your code here...
```

Read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Creating_a_Plugin) and [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/) for more info about creating plugins. It'll help you getting started.

Comment: i will definitely do that. am just checking that everything is ok or not.Thanks for your advise .